# Unable to track hubspot form submission on Google tag manager

Tags: iframe, google-tag-manager, hubspot

I want to track hubspot form submission on my website. I have used the technique provided by three white hats. However, no event is registering on success.THere is one listener tag, trigger, and one tag to pass this information to GA4. Apart from that, I have also created one variable for hubspot GUID.
The hubspot form listener tag

window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
    if(event.data.type === 'hsFormCallback' && event.data.eventName === 'onFormSubmitted') {
      window.dataLayer.push({
        'event': 'hubspot-form-success',
        'hs-form-guid': event.data.id
      });
    }
  });

The listener tag is firing with the intial container load. However no event is registering for hubspot form submission

Comment: Is there a reason to not use the built-in [form submission trigger](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/7679217?hl=en)? This could be more straightforward for you.
Otherwise, since your code looks OK I'd check if the js event is actually fired and the two conditions are fulfilled to push to dataLayer.

Comment: built in form submission trigger is not working for hubspot forms as they are loaded through iframes.

Comment: I can't debug what I don't have access to but in order to check if the events are being triggered correctly you can use `monitorEvents(window, 'message')` in DevTools console before you trigger a form submission. If all of the event properties should pass your check it means you have a problem with your GTM setup. It might be best to have someone take a look at it at that point.